# Quality issue of image after scaling in android

Tags: android, resize, scale

I'm making a photo editing app.

My app has a function to attach stickers, and if I make these stickers smaller using 'setScaleX', 'setScaleY' and save the editing results, the sticker quality will be seriously bad. Do you have any other ideas?

ps. The default size of the sticker is 600x600, and it doesn't break on a scale similar to this.

Comment: Well, I never worked with this but I think it's better if you use SVGs.

Comment: In my opinion the best option is using svg too